# How to make a function that doesn't take the element as a parameter like fadeIn

Tags: jquery, function

Hey guys I want to make a function like let's say : fadeIn()
The fadeIn() function doesn't take any parameters but it automatically knows what element I'm talking about.
Example: 
How I know how to make a function:

```js
function make100HW(el){
  $(el).animate({height:"100px",width:"100px"},400);
}

make100HW("#something");

//what I want is something like
// $("#something").make100HW(); without putting the element inside the parameters.
//just like $("#something").fadeIn();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something" style="background:red">
</div>
```

Comment: https://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/

Comment: I'm surprised not to find a **clean** "How do I make a jQuery plugin" dupetarget.

Comment: I didn't know that this was called a plugin :p
And thanks @A.Wolff

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make a jQuery plugin, you add the function to the `jQuery.fn` object (which is usually also available via `$.fn`, but a well-written plugin shouldn't assume `$` refers to jQuery). Within the function, `this` will be the jQuery set on which the plugin was called (**not** an individual DOM element as it is in event handler callbacks and such).

Often, the plugin will be complex enough to need ancillary functions. For that reason and because you shouldn't rely in `$`, it's common to see the plugin code wrapped in an IIFE accepting `$` as a parameter and passing in `jQuery`:

```
(function($) {
    // Code using $ here, which is fine even though noConflict
    // may have been used in the global context...
})(jQuery);
```

So:

```js
// Your plugin code
(function($) {
    $.fn.make100HW = function make100HW() {
        // 1. Use `this`, which is hte current jQuery set
        // 2. Return `this`, for chaining (which animate does)
        return this.animate({height:"100px",width:"100px"},400);
    };
})(jQuery);

// Using it
$("#something").make100HW();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="something" style="background:red">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

By creating a jQuery function:

```
$.fn.make100HW = function() {
  // You can now use $(this) as the selected element(s):
  $(this).animate({height:"100px",width:"100px"},400);
};
```

*That you could've Googled very easily, or find it in the jQuery docs. The reason I responded is to suggest better naming:*
Your function is now hardcoded, you can only do one thing with it, which is kind of a waste of functions. With a small tweak and better naming, you can use it for any size:

```
$.fn.makeSquare = function(size) {
  const useSize = size || 100;
  $(this).animate({height: useSize,width: useSize},400);
};
```

Answer (score -1):

before set element height and width 100px you put the code in css

```
#something{opacity:0}
```

```js
function make100HW(el){
  $(el).animate({"height":"100px","width":"100px","opacity":"1"},400);
}
```

also you do this

```
function make100HW(el){
  $(el).css({"opacity":"0"}}).animate({"height":"100px","width":"100px","opacity":"1"},400);
}
```

Comment: Not the downvote, but: This doesnt answer the question. OP asks how to turn a function into a jQuery function, which isn't a part of your explanation. Also, OP doesnt ask for a fade function, he/she provided it as example